# Why I have limited fonts in my editor in SP 2010?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

[image]I am using sharepoint 2010. When I create a new page and try to select another font in the editor, I see limited fonts. Where are the other default fonts on a windows machine?

I am looking for the font Corbel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @RobertLindgren writes it's only showing commonly available font, but it's controlled by CSS so you can change it.

If you're sure that the font is available for all (or at least most) of your users then you can add that to the list by inserting a style into your page or css as:

```
.ms-rteThemeFontFace-3
{
  -ms-name:"Corbel";
  font-family:"Corbel", sans-serif;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This list shows only standard fonts that are available on all platforms, including for example Mac. So all your Windows specific fonts are not available.

I also think that Microsoft has made the list short to not confuse the users and make the sites look to ugly.